# fatal error C1010: Возможно, вы забыли добавить директиву "#include "pch.h"" в источник

Tags: c++

При компилировании этого кода:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class b;
class a {
    friend int sum(a, b);
private:
    int i;
public:
    a() {
        cout << "Enter i: ";
        cin >> i;
    }
};

class b {
    friend int sum(a, b);
private:
    int y;
public:
    b() {
        cout << "Enter y: ";
        cin >> y;
    }
};

int sum(a first, b second) {
    return (first.i + second.y);
}

int main() {

    a first;
    b second;
    cout << sum(first, second) << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

выдает ошибку

> fatal error C1010: непредвиденный конец файла во время поиска предкомпилированного заголовка. Возможно, вы забыли добавить директиву "#include "pch.h"" в источник.

Почему так - непонятно. Все библиотеки подключил. (Работал в VS)

Comment: Ну а в .cpp  есть подключение файла?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1010?view=vs-2017

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится (или приведенный код ее не демонстрирует), прекомпилированный заголовочный файл тут подключен.

Comment: ты как проект создавал? создавал пустой и добавлял файлы? Если да, то тогда создай проект консольное приложение и все там автоматически все будет

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете или недоговариваете. При компиляции этого кода такой ошибки нет и быть не может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы не используете предварительно скомпилированные заголовки в своем проекте, установите для свойства Создать / Использовать предварительно скомпилированные заголовки исходных файлов значение Не использовать предварительно скомпилированные заголовки. Чтобы установить этот параметр компилятора, выполните следующие действия:

- На панели «Обозреватель решений» проекта щелкните правой кнопкой мыши
  имя проекта и выберите «Свойства».
- На левой панели щелкните папку C / C ++.
- Щелкните по узлу «Предварительно скомпилированные заголовки».
- На правой панели щелкните «Создать / использовать предварительно
  скомпилированный заголовок», а затем нажмите «Не использовать
  предварительно скомпилированные заголовки».

Убедитесь, что вы случайно не удалили, не переименовали или не удалили файл заголовка (по умолчанию stdafx.h) из текущего проекта. Этот файл также должен быть включен перед любым другим кодом в ваших исходных файлах с использованием #include "stdafx.h". (Этот заголовочный файл указан как свойство проекта «Создать / использовать PCH через файл»)
[Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1010?view=vs-2017)